# Dynamic URL with Vue/Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a Vue router which displays a given item and appends the items details to the url e.g. `http://localhost:8000/item/1?name=Glass%20Item&category=glass`.

This works fine as it is but the problem is if I refresh the page I get `404 not found`.

I have the items data saved to `localStorage`, is there a way to persist the given URL across refreshes?

Vue route:

```
    {
        name: "Item",
        path: "/item/:id",
        component: () =>
            import(/* webpackChunkName: 'item' */ "./pages/item.vue"),
        meta: {
    }
```

How I'm passing the items data:

```
            <router-link
                :to="{
                    name: 'Item',
                    params: { id: item.id },
                    query: { name: item.name, category: item.category }
                }"
            >
```

Laravel catch-all route:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'PagesController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

PagesController@index:

```
    public function index() {
        return view('layout.main');
    }
```

How I'm retrieving the items data (in ItemsController.php):

```
    public function index()
    {
        $items = Item::all();
        return response()->json($items);
    }
```

Have I gone about this in the wrong way? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you push `mode: 'history'` in VueRouter? And, `Route::get('/{any}', 'PagesController@index')->where('any', '.*');` at bottom of `routes/web.php`?

Comment: Yeah, this is my router: ```const router = new VueRouter({ mode: "history", routes: routes });``` and the ```Route::get...``` is at the bottom of ```routes/web.php```